# Ozeki is not returning other records

Tags: c#, ozeki

I'm doing an Ozeki Messenger Project using C#. I want to retrieve more than one record from the table. Its returning me the first record only...

Here's my code. Any Idea what am doing wrong guys?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String x;
        String y;
        String z;
        String SenderNumber, receiverNumber, message;
        SenderNumber = Request.QueryString.Get("sender");
        receiverNumber = Request.QueryString.Get("receiver");
        message = Request.QueryString.Get("msg");

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        connection.ConnectionString = Constring;
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT P_Name, P_Parking FROM tblPharmacy Where Code = '" + message + "'" ;

        connection.Open();

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();            
        String data = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            x = reader["P_Name"].ToString();
            y = reader["P_Parking"].ToString();
            data += x + "  " + y + " - ";

            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:9333/ozeki?login=admin&password=xxxxxx&action=sendMessage&messagetype=SMS:TEXT&recepient=" + SenderNumber + " &messageData= " + data);
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT P_Name, P_Parking FROM tblPharmacy Where Code = '" + message + "'` will only return those records for which code matches passed message. Check in the DB if you have more record for said Code

Comment: yes i have... If i type "all" in ozeki. it giving me only Ozeki par.. Not the others.

1 Hash Goodlands 2593326 Yes 8 10  PP
2 Ozeki somewhere 3692632 Par 9 10 all
4 noone elsewhere 5236982 Par 8 10 all
5 Disturbed whereelse 4569326 Park 9 10 all
6 disturbed hmmmmm 5966532 park 9 10 ON
7 Adeelah goodlands 5263963 park 8 10 ON
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Answer (score 0):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String x;
        String y;
        String z;
        String SenderNumber, receiverNumber, message;
        SenderNumber = Request.QueryString.Get("sender");
        receiverNumber = Request.QueryString.Get("receiver");
        message = Request.QueryString.Get("msg");

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    connection.ConnectionString = Constring;
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.CommandText = "SELECT P_Name, P_Parking FROM tblPharmacy Where Code = '" + message + "'" ;

    connection.Open();

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();            
    String data = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        x = reader["P_Name"].ToString();
        y = reader["P_Parking"].ToString();
        data += x + "  " + y + " - ";

    }
```

Response.Redirect("http://localhost:9333/ozeki?login=admin&password=xxxxxx&action=sendMessage&messagetype=SMS:TEXT&recepient=" + SenderNumber + " &messageData= " + data);
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

I got The Answer Myself.. LOL. The Response.Redirect should be outside the While Loop. It Works Just fine :D